# Image is not storing in phone storage instead storing in sdcard

Tags: android

I am using this code to store image in internal storage but image is not saving in phone storage, instead it is storing in sd card with path : /storage/sdcard0/DCIM/CAMERA/IMG_2345.,jpg

```
    private String saveToInternalMemory(Bitmap bitmap,String imgName){
    ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());

    File file = new File(getCacheDir(),"imageDirectory");

    //File directory = cw.getDir("imageDirectory", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    //File userDirectory = new File(directory,imgName);

    File myPath = new File(file,imgName);

    Log.e("path",myPath.getAbsolutePath());




    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(myPath);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100,fos);
        Log.e("img_name",bitmap.toString());


    }catch (FileNotFoundException e){}
    catch (IOException e){}finally {
        try {
            fos.close();
        }catch (IOException e){}
    }
    return myPath.getAbsolutePath();
}
```

Is phone storage and internal memory storage are same?
Actually when i am removing my sdcard then the image is storing in phone storage but if i reconnect my sdcard then by default it is storing in sdcard. How can i store my image by default in phone storage.
Our android's File storage shows two directories sdcard and phone storage, so image is storing in sdcard not in phone storage

Comment: On some devices you can select prefered storage. So maybe you have set in phone prefered storage on SD Card. `Adnroid Settings > Storage > prefered storage`. `getCacheDir()` should return prefered (internal) cache storage: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getCacheDir()

Comment: @Sanoop Can i see my stored image which is a .png because the image which is storing in sdcard is .jpg